# como pasar los datos txt leidos a un json como variable conn.request

Tags: python, archivo, variables, script, texto

Tengo el siguiente script, el cual ingresando los datos manualmente, lo ejecuta bien, sin embargo quiero leer un archivo txt y pasarle estos como variable, sin embargo no funciona, esto lo hago en python.

```
ram=open("file.txt","r")
i=0
for line in ram:
    print(line)
    line_limpio=line.strip() #lo uso para eliminar saltos de linea
    api_name='/api/Custom/Customer:%s' %line_limpio # lo que intento aqui es que guarde la variable asi /api/Custom/Customer:Sample
    

    #se inicia una conexion JSON
    import http.client
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https://mx.xxxx.com:500")
    payload = ""
    headers = { 'Authorization': "Bearer eyNgerBQu0KlidvkF9SNoI2gPw" }
    conn.request("GET", "/api/Custom/Customer:Sample", payload, headers) # quiero pasar como argumento api_name y susutituir "/api/Custom/Customer:Sample"
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    
    #guardar en log llamado salida
    archivo = open("salida.txt","a")
    archivo.write(str((data)))
    archivo.write("\n")
    archivo.close()

print("\nfin de archivo")
ram.close()
```

el contenido de txt es así:

```
Sample
Sample2
Sample3
```

Comment: por favor dale a [edit] y da de forma muy clara un ejemplo de entrada, algo que te funcione y qué te da ahora, así como qué no funciona exactamente. Son muchas líneas de código

Comment: gracias por tus comentarios, según yo si lo había editado para que se entendiera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia!

Que bueno que preguntas pues tienes que tener en cuenta varias cosas.

La primero es si el servicio que estas consultando te devuelve correctamente el JSON que tu necesitas. Si ese es el caso pues esta libreria en particular no te traera la respuesta como un diccionario, recuerda que los diccionarios en python son el equivalente a un JSON, y si conseguimos pasar esa respuesta a diccionario podremos crear ese archivo JSON que tu necesitas.

http.client devuelve unos bytes entonces tendremos que decodificarlos.

Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es decodificar la respuesta.

Una vez decodifiquemos la respuesta con el formato correcto, tendremos que utilizar json.dump para exportar el dict a un archivo.

```
ram = open("file.txt", "r")
i = 0
for line in ram:
    print(line)
    line_limpio = line.strip()  # lo uso para eliminar saltos de linea
    api_name = '/api/Custom/Customer:%s' % line_limpio  # lo que intento aqui es que guarde la variable asi /api/Custom/Customer:Sample

    # se inicia una conexion JSON
    import http.client

    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https://mx.xxxx.com:500")
    payload = ""
    headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer eyNgerBQu0KlidvkF9SNoI2gPw"}
    conn.request("GET", "/api/Custom/Customer:Sample", payload,
                 headers)  # quiero pasar como argumento api_name y susutituir "/api/Custom/Customer:Sample"
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    # Es importante conocer el formato de codificacion de tu respuesta puede ser utf-8 o utf-16 etc...
    json_data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))

    # guardar en log llamado salida
    with open('salida.json', 'w') as archivo:
        json.dump(json_data, archivo)

print("\nfin de archivo")
ram.close()
```

Me cuentas si te sirve, un salido :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Santiago, funciono.

Comment: Que bueno, podrias marcar la respuesta como correcta? eso me ayudaria un monton! feliz dia